# How to initialize tags array list in Elasticsearch and Python

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

I want to initialize an empty array like this below. How can I do that ?

```
"hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "customers",
                "_type": "customer",
                "_id": "QOTzXMUcrnbsYyFKeouHnjlkjQB3",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "uid": "QOTzXMUcrnbsYyFKeouHnjlkjQB3",
                    "email": "george@gmail.com",
                    "favorites": [],  < ---- this is the problem
                    "history": [],
                    "settings": {},
                    "purchases ": [],
                    "created": 1507892081201,
                    "updated": 1507892081201
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to STOF, I hv tried to answer based on what I understood, but if it's not what you are looking for, feel free to update the question and I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Let me know if you have further ques, will be happy to help.

Comment: would be great if you can comment on your question and provide feedback on my answer

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got your question properly, but as mentioned if you want to avoid `[]` values in your empty arrays, you can simply use the `null` value so that you can search and index these `null` values. please refer [null values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/null-value.html) official docs of elasticsearch.